# Read avro messages from kafka to PySpark 2.2

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am using kafka Confluent 4.0.0 to fetch data from SQL Server into kafka topics.

I want to read topics data stored in kafka from spark streaming program using below program:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer

schema_registry_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url='http://schemaregistryhostip:8081')
serializer = MessageSerializer(schema_registry_client)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["topic name"], {"metadata.broker.list": "brokerip:9092"}, valueDecoder=serializer.decode_message)
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
lines.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But I am getting below error when I start spark streaming using the method ssc.start().

```
ImportError: No module named confluent_kafka.avro.serializer
```

Comment: there is a comment here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/41 telling If you CD to a path that is NOT in /src/confluent-kafka-python then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, for your input. Actually my problem was resolved, after I made changes in schema-registry.properties file in confluent kafka. I changed listeners=http://localhost:8081 to listeners=http://Actual IP:8081 & then I was able to read topics data stored in confluent kafka from spark streaming program.